# What do you call a file name without the extension?

Tags: filesystems

Given the file name `foo/bar.baz`, we can say that `foo/` is the **dirname**, `bar.baz` is the **basename** and `.baz` is the **extname**. But is there a similar term that we can use for the `foo/bar` or `bar` part — i.e., the “file name sans extension”?

Comment: Maybe **stem** is a good term — **stemname**?

Answer (score 5):

I have been using "mantissa" in my code's comments for years.
For a computer floating point number the mantissa is just the numbers without
the power. I think of the extension as like the power.

Example:
123E56 where the mantissa is 123

1.23E56 is not a correct form and needs to be adjusted to 123E54 and once
again the mantissa is 123

So for floating point numbers that have a first part which contains a decimal point the power simply needs to be adjusted to move the decimal point all the way to the right.

Also there is a key stoke on some HP calculators that will show the mantissa with all digits without the power.

So for filenames when I leave the extension off what is left is the mantissa.  And the period is not included in the mantissa just like it is not included in a floating point number(depending on the type of floating point representation that is.)

foo.bar : the mantissa is foo

A similar logic can be used for the logarithm mathematical use of the term mantissa that I think also parallels to filenames.

I hope this catches on because we really need a name for that part.
And I vote for "mantissa" since I already have thousands of lines of code with
comments using "mantissa" and I'm not going to change them. Like anyone reads my comments anyway. I write a comment line for just about every line of code. And I create a flow chart file as well.

Comment: Wikipedia also notes: `This use of the word mantissa stems from an older, non-numerical, meaning: a minor addition or supplement, e.g., to a text.` I'll adopt it.

Answer (score 3):

In c++ (std::filesystem lib), it's **"stem"**
(https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/stem)

In PHP, it's **"filename"**
(https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

In Python, it's **"stem"**
(https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.stem)

Answer (score 2):

**base name**

[wikipedia/Filename](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename)
[ruby/File#basename](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File.html#method-c-basename)

Comment: In Python basename includes extension :(

Comment: Unfortunately, this is incorrect. If you look at the method documentation you referenced, it says `File.basename("/home/gumby/work/ruby.rb") #=> "ruby.rb"`, which means that calling `basename` will return the filename *with* the file extension. Unless you provide a suffix (i.e. the extension) as the 2nd param that you wish the `basename` method to remove.

Answer (score 0):

Great question and, honestly, based on my experience and Googling, it's a little subjective.

I like to look at how existing languages handle this for two reasons:

1. Because really smart people spend time debating and building these languages.
2. Ultimately, we need to use these languages to get anything done so the closer we align with what they do and name things, the easier that will be.

So two that I'll look at because they are extremely handy for me right now:

#### Javascript

```js
path.parse( "foo/bar.baz" )
//=> { root: '', dir: 'foo', base: 'bar.baz', ext: '.baz', name: 'bar' }
```

**Javascript calls the file name without the extension the `name`.**

#### Ruby

```rb
File.basename("foo/bar.baz")
#=> "bar.baz"
File.basename("foo/bar.baz", ".baz")
#=> "bar"
```

**Ruby doesn't have a name for the file name without the extension.**

So, there doesn't seem to be a correct, standard answer here. I would try and follow what the language you are using does and/or stick with something that makes sense to you and your team and, most importantly, **be consistent**.