# How to create a zip files from different files extensions using python

Tags: python, windows

I have a folder that contains many files with the same name with different extensions, I want to zip the files according to the filenames. Is there a way I can learn?

[image]

Comment: You can learn by _doing_. Open your favorite code editor, and try to solve the problem yourself by thinking about it and writing some code. When you hit a wall, you can come back here and ask _specific questions_ about _specific problems_ you're facing :)

Comment: I don't think the word "compress" means what you think it means.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen is it a library? sorry i'm new to python

Comment: @Sören , sorry, i mean create zip file

Comment: This problem neatly decomposes into 3 steps: 1. List all files 2. Group them by their [mantissa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13362022/what-do-you-call-a-file-name-without-the-extension/49374830#49374830) 3. Create a zip archive from a list of filenames. Which of these 3 do you need help with?

Comment: Is what a library? You need to solve a number of _problems_: 1) discover files in a particular folder, 2) grouping files together by partial common name, 3) creating a zip archive and adding those files. Either one of those (but probably most definitely step 3) might involve using a specific library. Happy coding

Comment: The `powershell` tag seems superfluous for a Python script?

Comment: IMHO `pathlib` is a good, modern way of processing filenames. Good tutorial here https://pymotw.com/3/pathlib/index.html

Comment: @Sören Thanks for your help, I'll try to learn it based on the steps you gave, grouping by filename/mantissa first, then zip the files. I hope I can understand quickly.
@MathiasR.Jessen I thought "doing" is the name of the library. Thank you for your help.
@MarkSetchell Sorry, i will delete it and thanks for your advice. I will try to learn `pathlib`

Comment: @apinpipin welcome to StackOverflow - it looks like you got some useful tips. For future questions, please limit your question to a more specific subject and share some code you wrote trying to solve the problem. A very open question like "is there a way I can learn?" often gets closed without answer, while a specific question like "why doesn't this piece of code work, I expected X?" will see answers and may help others as well. More here "[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"